# Centering Text Inside A Colored Inset Border Textbox

Tags: colors, textbox, center, permanent, insets

I'm new to html & css, and I'm trying to have non-editable (permanent) centered text inside a colored inset border textbox. I can't seem to get permanent text within the textbox. Any text I type seems to go outside of the textbox.The 9px inset part isn't working as well. I have attatched a picture of what I'm trying to do. Here's my code that I'm using:
 html:

```
Page <input size="3" name="uid"> of 1
```

css: `INPUT,SELECT,TEXTAREA

{background-color: black;
color: white;`
`border:9px inset #2121;
border-color: #444;}`

`INPUT,SELECT {
            font-size: x-small;
        }`

Picture:    https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2QeO.png Here's some code that I found that makes text appear un-editable. I'm unsure how to change the border color & size in html though.     http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_border-style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `text-align: center;` to your style for the input

Comment: I added some missing information. Thanks for your reply, it's much appreciated ^_^

Comment: You could use `padding` or `margin` and their variants such as `padding: 10px 20px;` or `padding-bottom: 10px;` in your style. Play around with that. You could also try `height: 30px;`, `width: 60px;` and border-color can be set by `border: 9px inset #444;'. Take out the #2121 - that's not even a color.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Adding text-align helped. Here's the code that I'm using now. HTML: `page <input size="3" id="uid" value="1"> of 1' CSS: `#uid {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 border: 2px inset #444;
 border-color: #f5f5f5;
 text-align: center;
        width: 33px;
}`